# Rails 3 Find all records from has_many :through without collision from previous has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :books, :through => :favorites
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :book_id, :presence => true
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorite
end
```

The idea is that a user can own a book and add a book from another user as favorite. In `rails console`, i tried `User.find(1).favorites.books` but got a NoMethodError: undefined method `books'. And`user.books` only returns the books owned by that user

Is there any way to retrieve all books that belong to a user's favorite in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close, but you shouldn't have two associations name `books`.  Try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_books, :through => :favorites, :source => :book
end
```

Then your query would simply be `User.find(1).favorites_books`